# Python 3 list result out of SQL

Tags: python

One question to results out of MySQL in Python.
I'm running in Python following SQL against MySQL:

```
results = list(db_select("SELECT filename FROM qry_filenames;"))
```

Results are e.g.

```
[('./results/file1.pdf',), ('./results/file2.pdf',), ('./results/file3',)]
```

Unfortunately, I need the results in this way:

```
['./results/file1.pdf', './results/file2.pdf', './results/file3']
```

Any idea how to convert the list?
Thank you in advance

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the tuple index to get the right element out of them.

```
results_list = [tup[0] for tup in results]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! Best regards - Andreas